# Winston/Node.js how add a Transport only for certain environment?

Tags: node.js, winston

I have the follow configuration:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var Mail = require('winston-mail').Mail;

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: 'info', colorize: true }),
    new (winston.transports.File)({ level: 'info', filename: './logs/logs.log',
    new (Mail)({
              to: 'xxxxxx@xxxxxx.xx',
              from: 'winston@xxxxx.xx',
              subject: 'Errors occurred',
              level: 'error',
              host: 'smtp.xxxxx.xx',
              username: 'xxxx@xxxx.xx', 
              password: 'xxxxx',
              port: xxx
            })
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)(),
    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './logs/exceptions.log' }),
    new (Mail)({
              to: 'xxxxxx@xxxxxx.xx',
              from: 'winston@xxxxx.xx',
              subject: 'Errors occurred',
              level: 'error',
              host: 'smtp.xxxxx.xx',
              username: 'xxxx@xxxx.xx', 
              password: 'xxxxx',
              port: xxx
            })
 ]
});
```

I'd like add the Mail transport only for production environment not in staging or development.

I set a different log level as follow:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  logger.transports.console.level = 'debug';
  logger.transports.file.level = 'debug';
}
```

There is a way to do that also with transport?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `transports` configuration is just a plain old [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). So we can use all the usual tricks on it. In this case, you want a conditional `push()`.

```
const winston = require('winston');
const transports = [
    new winston.transports.Console({
        level    : 'info',
        colorize : true
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
        level    : 'info',
        filename : './logs/logs.log'
    })
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const Mail = require('winston-mail').Mail;

    transports.push(new Mail({
        to       : 'xxxxxx@xxxxxx.xx',
        from     : 'winston@xxxxx.xx',
        subject  : 'Errors occurred',
        level    : 'error',
        host     : 'smtp.xxxxx.xx',
        username : 'xxxx@xxxx.xx', 
        password : 'xxxxx',
        port     : 1234
    }));
}

const logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports
});
```

This code should be usable as is on Node.js >= 4, after filling in the mail configuration placeholders.

The same principle can be applied to the `exceptionHandlers`.

Comment: As of winston 3.0 you can now call `logger.add(new winston.transports.Console(...))` on a logger you have already instantiated.