# Winston/Node.js how to add a Transport only for a certain routes?

Tags: node.js, express, winston, morgan

Let us say I have the following API's and their respective routes as following -

1) /api/v1/teachers - For CRUD operation of teachers

2) /api/v1/students - For CRUD operation of students

Currently, I am storing logs of both the API requests in combined.log file. I want to store logs of CRUD operations of teachers in teachers.log file and logs for CRUD operations of students in students.log file.

I have referred the following question in which the author wants to store certain logs based on certain environment.

[Winston/Node.js how add a Transport only for certain environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641543/winston-node-js-how-add-a-transport-only-for-certain-environment)

```
const winston = require('winston');
const transports = [
    new winston.transports.Console({
        level    : 'info',
        colorize : true
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
        level    : 'info',
        filename : './logs/logs.log'
    })
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const Mail = require('winston-mail').Mail;

    transports.push(new Mail({
        to       : 'xxxxxx@xxxxxx.xx',
        from     : 'winston@xxxxx.xx',
        subject  : 'Errors occurred',
        level    : 'error',
        host     : 'smtp.xxxxx.xx',
        username : 'xxxx@xxxx.xx', 
        password : 'xxxxx',
        port     : 1234
    }));
}
const logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports
});
```

But since I am not able to access the request object itself in winston.js so I can not apply a condition-based on routes to store logs of different routes in a different file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your 2 transports and use [express-winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-winston) to choose the specified transport before your router.

```
var router = require('./teachers-router');

app.use(expressWinston.logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.teachers, // you will need to create this one by your own
  ],
}));
app.use(router);
```